# SQLLDR: column with default value not filled

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I have a table in Oracle 11g I'm trying to load with SQLLDR. This table has a column that should contain the creation date that stores when this row was created in the database:

```
...
ORACLE_ROW_CREATE TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP
...
```

My control file looks like this:

```
INTO TABLE rrdbo.IBXR_STAGE_0000
WHEN (12-26) <> 'IBXRBASELINE   ' AND (30-47) <> BLANKS
   (
   CLIENT_GROUP_ID POSITION(1:10)
   , PORTAL_ID POSITION(11:20)
   , ACCOUNT_BRANCH_ID POSITION(21:23)
   , ACCOUNT_BASE_ID POSITION(24:29)
   , RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_CD POSITION(30)
   , CLIENT_ID POSITION(31:40)
   , CLIENT_SEGMENT_ID POSITION(41:45) DECIMAL EXTERNAL
   , TOA_IND POSITION(46)
   , LINK_TYPE_CD POSITION(47)
   , LST_UPD_TMST POSITION(48:67) TIMESTAMP "YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF6"
   , LST_UPD_PRCS_ID POSITION(68:77)
   , LST_UPD_ID POSITION(78:87)
   , MULTI_COMPANY_NUM CONSTANT "0000"
   )
```

After the load completes the ORACLE_ROW_CREATE column has no values. How do I provide this value without setting DIRECT=FALSE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [SYSDATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_field_list.htm#i1008302):

```
   , ORACLE_ROW_CREATE SYSDATE
```

But you'd lose millisecond precision. So more usefully in your case, youe can use  [`EXPRESSION`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_field_list.htm#i1008287) to pick up the column default:

```
   , ORACLE_ROW_CREATE EXPRESSION "DEFAULT"
```

The documentation explicitly says:

> In both conventional path mode and direct path mode, the EXPRESSION parameter can be used to load the default value into column_name

... so it won't be ignored as it normally would be for a direct-path load. (Although I've never actually used this, so I hope the docs are right...)